# Write Unit Test for NLog

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, moq, nlog

I have integrated NLog in my MVC5 project. I have to unit test it using Moq. Below is my attempt but I am confused about how should I validate the logging?

```
    public void LogInfomation_Test()
            {
                var logger = new Mock<NLogger>();
                var l = logger.Object;
                l.LogInfo("Info logging");
               //How Should I write Assert step here
           }
```

Comment: One of the normal tenants for unit testing is "don't test the framework": while 3rd party NLog is better considered part of the infrastructure. (The assumption is the authors of NLog test it themselves like you assume mscorlib is tested by Microsoft.) You would be better off testing your code.

Comment: Thanks for you reply @Richard. But I have written wrapper class "NLogger" and I have unit test it.

Comment: why don't you show us the method you're trying to test, rather than just the test? It is unclear what you're attempting to test when you're only given the (incomplete) test itself.